# Can't add HTML (button) to caption

Tags: html, css, wordpress, magnific-popup

I am using the "Wordpress Carousel Pro" plugin on my Wordpress site. That plugin uses the code from "Magnific Popup" to display a pop-up when you click an image. You can add text to the caption of an image and that text will be displayed on the popup but the caption doesn't take HTML it shows no HTML that I added

```
<a href="#" class="popup-button">Link Button</a>
```

Does anyone know why this happens? You can see what happens on this page https://videosafari.nl/tv/ on the first image of the first row I added a HTML button to the caption and you see things dont look good at all.

Apart from that I did manage to add this successfully.

```
<button>Default Button</button>
```

But when I want to add a link to that

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://w3docs.com';">Default</button>
```

It will not look like a button anymore and the result will be the same as with a normal button. (the first example). Does anyone know why this happens? Thank you in advance.

Regard,

Dean.

https://videosafari.nl/tv/

https://shapedplugin.com/plugin/wordpress-carousel-pro/

https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: The plugin is probably stripping out HTML attributes using a filter. Look in the plugin code to see where the caption is being set. Without seeing the code, we can't really help you.

Comment: It does work when i only use single quotes. Do you think this is the right solution or will it cause problems in the future? <a href='https://www.npostart.nl/helden-van-het-maxima/AT_2123767/overview' class='lightbox-play-button'>&#x25b6;︎ Afspelen</a>

Comment: Single quotes are valid value enclosures, so if it works, I say go with it! I can't say what will happen in the future - if an update to the plugin will prevent that.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with it for now.